# Rotation and translation around arbitrary axis

Tags: 3d

I am trying to figure out how to translate/move in arbitrary coordinate system from some sample problems. Its giving me headache..

Ok so I have a tank at point Q sitting on a plane with normal N. I want to rotate it (in place), say 30 degress to its right, and move it K units forward. I sort of figured out how arbitrary rotation works, but I am not quite sure if I am getting this correctly.

Say tanks position is defined with a 3x3 M matrix.

So to rotate in arbitrary space I would do something like this:

M = (Q^-1)(Rx^-1)(Ry^-1)(Rz)(Ry)(Rx)(Q)

where Rz = rotation at -30 deg around z-axis

is this right?

But now I also want to move it K units along its new direction.. So I have to add a translation matrix in there somewhere. I think it should go before Rz (not sure)

M = (Q^-1)(Rx^-1)(Ry^-1)(Tk)(Rz)(Ry)(Rx)(Q)

Is this even correct? Or I got it all wrong? Any math geniuses out there?

thanks :)

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution? What program, language will you be writing the expression with

Comment: Look up rotation matrix. Or, if your language supports complex numbers, learn how to multiply by vectors of modulus 1.

Answer (score 0):

What's your programmation's language? I think you can find a library that permit you to make it the easy way. By example openCL in c++. A lot of 3D libraries already exist, it's a very useful gain of time to use them.

Comment: im trying to understand the math behind this

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you for math

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted the new tank position, I can help. I've been doing something similar, and I had a time doing this too. If you are doing this in 3d, then you can apply this to each coordinate of the tank.

First, you need to assume that the tank is the center of the world, ie, local coordinates.
Then you need to move it forward K units, so it is at (0, K)

Then you need to use matrices to turn the point by θ (in radians) and produce:

```
newX = (x*math.cos(θ))-(y*math.sin(θ))
newY = (x*math.sin(θ))+(y*math.cos(θ))
```

(from code I used myself, so I know it works)